How to validate uniqueness with scope when model belongs to a model that belongs to another model
I have a simple situation where we need to have unique SKUs for items for sale. A location has many products and a product has many variants. The SKUs for each variant has to be unique for a location. I assumed something like this would work but it gives an error.
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :variants
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  validates :sku, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: product.location.id}
end


just use custom validation

How important is uniqueness to you? If you just have a validation in your application it's going to be very prone to race conditions. I would consider putting location_id onto the variants table which would let you add a simple uniqueness constraint on the table as well as handle the case where a location may just have a few variants of a product.
